# Defining the indexed union/intersection formally in $\mathsf{ZFC}$

Tags: set-theory

An indexed set is often informally defined as $\{A_i: i \in \mathcal{I}\}$. But this is informal in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, since it doesn't know indices. Likewise, this problem carries over to the definition of an indexed union/intersection (we will limit ourselves to union for simplicity).

$$
\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_i = \{x:\exists i \in \mathcal{I}(x \in A_i)\}.
$$

This has troubled me for some time and got me thinking how to formalize it. We could change notation and say that the argument of the union operator is a function with the domain $\mathcal{I}$ and an arbitrary codomain. Our function set being $F$, this would be the rough result:

$$
\bigcup_{i\in\mathcal{I}}F = \{x : \exists f \in F\exists i \in \mathcal{I}\exists A(f = (i,A) \land x \in A)\}.
$$

This definition restricts us to the definition of $F$, for which we must always choose a codomain. But maybe we can do better due to Replacement. Consider this (the omission of a symbol after the union symbol is not a mistake):

$$
\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}} = \bigcup\{z : z \in \varphi[\mathcal{I}]\land \exists i\in \mathcal{I} \varphi(i,z)\},
$$

where $\varphi$ is a formula of which it holds that $\forall x(x \in \mathcal{I} \to \exists!y\varphi(x,y))$ and $\varphi[\mathcal{I}]$ is a projection of $\mathcal{I}$ by $\varphi$, whose existence Replacement guarantees.

So, what do you think? Was my attempt successful? I'm interested in all criticisms and improvements.

Comment: "...for which we must always choose a codomain..." I don't see why. In set-theory we can define a function $F$ as a set of ordered pairs that has a special property (for every set $a$ there is at most one $b$ with $(a,b)\in F$). So the mentioning of any codomain is not necessary.

Comment: @drhab That is true, thanks. This is apparent from the fact that the codomain doesn't appear in the definition. I guess the advantage of the second definition would be that we only need $\mathcal{I}$.

Answer (score 1):

ZFC **does** know indices: it models them as the arguments of functions. The standard way of explicating the indexed union notation goes like this. $I$ is some set and $A : I \to X$ is a function from $I$ to some set $X$. We adopt the convention of writing $A_i$ rather than $A(i)$ for the value of $A$ at $i \in I$. We then write $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_i$ as a short-hand for:

$$\bigcup\{Y \mid \exists i (Y = A_i)\} = \{x \mid \exists Y, i(Y = A_i \land x \in Y)\}
$$.

We don't need to appeal to replacement for the existence of the above set (because everything is contained within the range $X$ of the function $A$).